# PHP file uploading but can't find in directory

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I've checked several methods on stackoverflow but none is able to solve this.
I've made an html form to input **file** type through **SELF_PHP** form.
*Seems like PHP is uploading the file correctly but the directory to which it's being uploaded is empty* . Here's the code:
**HTML**

```
<form method="post" id="fileUpForm" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    Select image to upload: 
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php 
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
 ?>
```

Additional Info: .php file directory - `/var/www/html/FileUp.php`
uploads directory(to store files) - `/var/www/html/uploads/`
Code used(modified) from : '*schools.com'

Comment: check folder permissions and errors http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: You can leave out the `action="..."` if you're posting to the same page. Other than that, you must use [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) since it gets put in a temp directory and deleted otherwise.

Comment: you code does not contain any spot where the posted file is saved.

Comment: @Fred-ii- permissions - **root**

Comment: RTM http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php Edit: as @cmorrissey said.

Comment: also you took this example from http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp go to the bottom where it says "Complete Upload File PHP Script" that's what you need to use, not the first script at the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any "move" with your file. You have it uploaded in temporary memory, now you have to move it whenever you want.

Use [PHP: move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

```
<?php 
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        // if check is ok, move the file to the target directory
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir)
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: That's all been said in comments http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36557537/1. Edit: So now there's code.

Comment: `"../directory"` ? so why not just use the right syntax and use the variable?

Comment: Thanks for solution, today I learned never to refer w3schools again. Thanks all

Comment: w3s is great when you are learning basics, but it is not a place where you should look for whole examples.